# Fama Macbeth Regression: Culture and Momentum

Tags: regression, statistical-finance, behavioral-finance

I am attempting to replicate the work from "Individualism and Momentum around the World" (Shui, Titman, Wei, 2010, [link](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2009.01532.x)) but I am not sure how to run a Fama Macbeth regression where the independent variable (individualism, in this case, is not time series in nature) and the dependent variable are momentum portfolio returns.

Comment: In a first step the Fama Macbeth is run on many individual countries (See Table III) in the usual manner. In a second step the country results are grouped into 3 categories (hi, medium, low individulism countries) and the average momentum returns of the three groups are compared.

Comment: Thank you. I am referring to the regressions in Section VI. I am unsure how to execute these regressions given that some data points do not vary over time